# Data structures singly circular linked list

Tags: c, data-structures, singly-linked-list

Here's my code for Singly Linked List:

```
void addtoempty(int data)
{
    if (last->next == NULL)
    {
        struct node* new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        new_node->data = data;
        last->next = new_node;
        new_node->next = new_node;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("element exists\n");
    }
}

void insert(int data)
{
    if (last->next == NULL)
        addtoempty(data);
    else
    {
        // intf("now insert vl happen\n");
        struct node* new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        new_node->data = data;
        new_node->next = last->next;
        last->next->next = new_node;
        last->next = new_node;
    }
}

void display()
{
    print = last->next->next;
    do
    {
        printf("%d \t", print->data);
        print = print->next;
    } while (print != last->next->next);
    printf("\n");
}
```

I want to insert an element after a node in singly circular linked list using only tail pointer. Is it possible? If yes, how? And in the above program, what changes should be made to `insert()` to achieve the above result?

Comment: Which node do you want to insert after?  Is `last` a global variable?  (How uncouth!)  Why on earth is `print` a global variable?  That's just awful.  It should be a local variable.  There's a partial excuse for using a global for `last`, but not for `print`.

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? What makes you think that the code does not already achieve what you want?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is in `insert`.  You're setting three `next` pointers:

```
new_node->next = last->next;
last->next->next = new_node;
last->next = new_node;
```

You should only be setting two:

```
new_node->next = last->next;
last->next = new_node;
```

The third one, which set `last->next->next`, was effectively removing the rest of the list.